# Why is a linear function bounded below on $R^n$ only when it is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I learnt from a book that ***a linear function is bounded below on $R^n$ only when it is zero***.

The example in the book shows that the inequality { $a^TFx\geqslant b-a^Tg$ } holds only when { $a^TF=0$ }, where $a\neq0$, $F\in R^{m\times n}$, $x\in R^n$, $b\in R$ and $g\in R^m$, and $x$ is the variable.

How does the conclusion come out? Or is there any place I misunderstood?

Comment: What here is playing the role of the variable? Is $x$ fixed (but arbitrary) or is $a$ fixed (but arbitrary)?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I modified. Its $x$.

Comment: copper.hat answered this question on: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305246/bounded-linear-function-implication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a^T F$ weren't zero, $x \mapsto a^T Fx$ were a linear function bounded below (namely by $b - a^T g \in \mathbf R$) that is not zero.

To prove your first sentence, suppose $f \colon \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R$ is a non zero linear function, say $f(x) \ne 0$. To show it is not bounded below, let $M \in \mathbf R$ be arbitrary. Suppose $f(x) > 0$ (otherwise replace $x$ by $-x$ noting that $f(-x) = -f(x)$). Now note that for $\lambda \in \mathbf R$, we have $$ f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x) $$
By choosing $\lambda < \frac{M}{f(x)}$, we have 
$$ f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x) < \frac{M}{f(x)} \cdot f(x) = M $$
we see that $M$ is no lower bound for $f$. As $M$ was arbitrary, $f$ is unbounded below.